# Django ignoring localisation settings when displaying a DateTime on a form

Tags: python, django

I have the Django settings in "settings.py":

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

With a model in "models.py":

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

And a form in "forms.py":

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ['date_time']
```

And in the template:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="javascript:window.location='/dashboard';">Cancel
    </button>
</form>
```

But the date is shown on the screen in the form as "2020-12-20 10:11:12" for example. Why doesn't Django use my localisation settings and display the date as "day, month, year"?

I tried adding to the form:

```
 date_time = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'])
```

...but it didn't have any effect.

To quote the manual on DATETIME_FORMAT: "The default formatting to use for displaying datetime fields in any part of the system. Note that if USE_L10N is set to True, then the locale-dictated format has higher precedence and will be applied instead."

Comment: This is the *input* format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the `input_formats` parameter, so the list of formats that is accepted to *parse* the input, not render it. You can specify the way to *format* the data with the [**`format=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.DateTimeInput.format) of the widget:

```
date_time = forms.DateTimeField(
    input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M']
    widget=forms.DateTimeInput(format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

> the date is shown on the screen in the form as "2020-12-20 10:11:12"
> for example.

Are you talking about the date and time shown in Django Admin section?

If so, this happens because the `TIME_ZONE` and `USE_TZ` in settings do not apply to the data shown in django-admin section, but only to data shown in templates.

As far as I know, Django natively does not allow to change timezone for admin, because the all time data used by admins is meant to have the same landmark. It's like all admins should be using the same unit of measurement.

However, as suggested [here](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/52710743.shtml), you could set a timezone for each admin user, so that every admin sees the timedate data of the admin section expressed according to his/her timezone.